# How to downgrade the JDK version of Java EE site

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets, java, java-5

I tried to host my java application. But the server has only Tomcat 5.5.4 and JDK version 1.5. The Java EE application I have build is having Tomcat 7.0.34 and JDK 1.7. Now I have been told to down grade the JDK and Tomcat version. Does any body know to downgrade the same. I also want to know what is the Java EE and Servlet version supported by JDK 5.5.4

Is it enough if I only change the JDK  version to 1.5 and keep the Tomcat version at 7.0.34. Will it  run in the server where the Tomcat version is 5.5.4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I you have to downgrade your code to be compatible with Tomcat 5 and JDK 1.5, then you can't just downgrade your code to JDK 1.5. You also need to downgrade to Tomcat 5.

I would advice you to look for another hoster though. JDK 1.6 ((Java SE 6) has already been end-of-lived. 1.5 is by all accounts *ancient*. Never trust a hoster that forces ancient tech upon you!

Comment: I downgraded the application. And I got the same problem you mentioned . i had to downgrade my code. Thanks for the advice